# show Sencha List scrolling indicator

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

I am new to sencha touch.I want to indicate scrolling of the list.When the list is loaded i need to display the scrolling indicator.I am getting scrolling indicator on scrolling the list.but i want the indication on loading the list.
{
xtype:'list',
scrollable{
direction:'vertical',
indicators:true
}
}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

By default, there won't be scroll indicator. Scroll indicator is not necessary in HTML5 world. Please look at notification and friend list in facebook. The scroll won't be display all the time.

We have to extend the Sencha Touch functionality to implement this. Someone has implemented [this feature](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?270697-Always-show-scrollbar).

Otherwise, you implement your own method to do.

If you really need this, there are two choices,

1. You have to extend Sencha Touch functionality
2. Please use [this link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?270697-Always-show-scrollbar)
3. Use the following css

   .x-scroll-indicator {
   opacity: 0.5 !important;
   }

--Sridhar

Answer (score 0):

There is an autoHide configuration since Sencha Touch 2.3.0:

> "New in Touch 2.3.0, each indicator has an autoHide configuration that
>   allows you to control it. Setting autoHide to false will tell that
>   indicator not to auto-hide. You can use the indicators config within
>   the scrollable config on a Container or subclass."
>
> http://www.sencha.com/blog/top-support-tips-march-2014

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'container',
            html: 'The y scroll indicator will always show, x will hide as autoHide defaults to true',
            scrollable: {
                direction: 'both',
                indicators: {
                    y: {
                        autoHide: false
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1u9